# Inserting objects into array in Javascripts throws uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript

I am creating pos objects and inserting them into an array.

**Following is perfectly fine code.**

```
var pos1={lat:25,long:56};
var pos2={lat:100,long:200};
var pos3={lat:-63,long:-29};
var objects=[];
objects.push(pos1);
objects.push(pos2);
objects.push(pos3);
console.log(objects[0].lat+","+objects[0].long);
console.log(objects[1].lat+","+objects[1].long);
console.log(objects[2].lat+","+objects[2].long);
```

**Output**

[image]

Then I tried to insert some objects using random numbers inside a loop.It was precisely at this very point that it gave producing errors.

**Uncaught TypeError: When Pos Objects is Outside the loop**

```
var locations=[];
var pos={lat:0,long:0}; //Here post object is outside the loop
size=10;
for(var i=1;i<=size;i++){

var x=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*10);
var y=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*10);
pos.lat=x;
pos.long=y;
locations.push(pos);
}

for(var i=1;i<=size;i++){
console.log(locations[i].lat+","+locations[i].long);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**Uncaught TypeError: When Pos Objects is Inside the loop**

```
var locations=[];

size=10;
for(var i=1;i<=size;i++){
var pos={lat:0,long:0};   //pos object inside the loop
var x=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*10);
var y=Math.floor(1+Math.random()*10);
pos.lat=x;
pos.long=y;
locations.push(pos);
}


for(var i=1;i<=size;i++){
console.log(locations[i].lat+","+locations[i].long);
}
```

**Output**

[image]

**I am NOT getting why I am getting these errors.My understanding is that when accessing the locations array I need to caste it to the pos object?**

Comment: you are not considering that array index starts at zero.

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl I am really disappointed I did not realize that.........these are the very basics...............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` should be start from `0` like this:

```
for(var i=0;i < size;i++){
    console.log(locations[i].lat+","+locations[i].long);
}
```

As `array` index starts from `zero` and ends with less than 1 of its size.

Answer (score 2):

well in programming array index start from zero
so when size is 5 for example indices are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 .. see how the last index is 4 ..

In your case you iterate till `<=size` which is trying to access element which is not there and thats why you are getting the error

`i = 0 ; i < 10` should fix it

Answer (score 1):

Array indices starting with 0, so `i` must start with 0 and should only go `<` not `<=`

```js
var locations = [];

size = 10;
for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
    var pos = {
        lat: 0,
        long: 0
    }; //pos object inside the loop
    var x = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10);
    var y = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 10);
    pos.lat = x;
    pos.long = y;
    locations.push(pos);
}

for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    console.log(i, locations[i].lat + "," + locations[i].long);
}
```